# How to install a file under data/data/myapp/files folder?

Tags: android, deployment

I tried to put my file, say like, index.html under assets, but it was converted to a raw binary file with unreadable file name, however, I wanted to have that index.html intact deployed under app/files folder, what should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: See [Using the Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Create a `File` object via `new File(getFilesDir(), "index.html")`

Step #2: See if the `File` exists using `exists()`

Step #3: If the `File` does not exist, copy it from your assets using standard Java I/O